# Exception while executing service task in activiti,activiti engine Not able to locate class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, activiti, bpmn

i am developing a web project using spring mvc and activiti everything worked fine for simple user tasks, But when workflow reaches to service task in which a java method to be called exception is thrown. Project is running on eclipse using tomcat7 server.

```
org.activiti.engine.ActivitiIllegalArgumentException: Delegate expression com.nuc.service.DoService did neither resolve to an implementation of interface org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.delegate.ActivityBehavior nor interface org.activiti.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ServiceTaskDelegateExpressionActivityBehavior.execute(ServiceTaskDelegateExpressionActivityBehavior.java:81)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationActivityExecute.execute(AtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:45)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:88)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:532)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:527)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.eventNotificationsCompleted(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.java:52)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:56)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:88)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:532)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:527)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:49)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:88)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:532)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:527)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionCreateScope.execute(AtomicOperationTransitionCreateScope.java:49)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:88)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:532)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:527)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerTake.execute(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerTake.java:66)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:88)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:532)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:527)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionDestroyScope.execute(AtomicOperationTransitionDestroyScope.java:116)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:88)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:532)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:527)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerEnd.eventNotificationsCompleted(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerEnd.java:36)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:56)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:88)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:532)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:527)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:49)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:88)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:532)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:527)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.take(ExecutionEntity.java:367)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.BpmnActivityBehavior.performOutgoingBehavior(BpmnActivityBehavior.java:105)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.BpmnActivityBehavior.performDefaultOutgoingBehavior(BpmnActivityBehavior.java:54)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.FlowNodeActivityBehavior.leave(FlowNodeActivityBehavior.java:44)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.AbstractBpmnActivityBehavior.leave(AbstractBpmnActivityBehavior.java:47)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.UserTaskActivityBehavior.signal(UserTaskActivityBehavior.java:96)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.signal(ExecutionEntity.java:350)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TaskEntity.complete(TaskEntity.java:160)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.CompleteTaskCmd.execute(CompleteTaskCmd.java:39)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.CompleteTaskCmd.execute(CompleteTaskCmd.java:24)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.NeedsActiveTaskCmd.execute(NeedsActiveTaskCmd.java:61)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.execute(CommandInvoker.java:24)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:57)
at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:47)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:45)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:31)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:40)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:35)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.TaskServiceImpl.complete(TaskServiceImpl.java:168)
at com.gk.controller.MyController.complete(MyController.java:101)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

BPMN xml

```
 <process id="myProcess" name="My process" isExecutable="true">
<startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start"></startEvent>
<userTask id="usertask1" name="add new record" activiti:candidateUsers="user1" activiti:candidateGroups="m"></userTask>
<sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="usertask1"></sequenceFlow>
<userTask id="usertask2" name="approve record" activiti:candidateUsers="user2" activiti:candidateGroups="c"></userTask>
<sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="usertask1" targetRef="usertask2"></sequenceFlow>
<serviceTask id="servicetask1" name="Service Task" activiti:delegateExpression="com.nuc.service.DoService"></serviceTask>
<endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
<sequenceFlow id="flow3" sourceRef="servicetask1" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
<sequenceFlow id="flow4" sourceRef="usertask2" targetRef="servicetask1"></sequenceFlow>
```

beans.xml

```
    <bean id="doService" class="com.nuc.service.DoService">
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource">
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/activitiDb" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />

</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>


<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="false" />
    <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="false" />

</bean>

<bean id="processEngine" class="org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
</bean>
<bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngine"
    factory-method="getRepositoryService" />
<bean id="runtimeService" factory-bean="processEngine"
    factory-method="getRuntimeService" />
<bean id="taskService" factory-bean="processEngine"
    factory-method="getTaskService" />
<bean id="historyService" factory-bean="processEngine"
    factory-method="getHistoryService" />
<bean id="managementService" factory-bean="processEngine"
    factory-method="getManagementService" />
```

DoService

```
import org.activiti.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution;
import org.activiti.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.delegate.ActivityExecution;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class DoService implements JavaDelegate{

public void execute(DelegateExecution arg0) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("service task");
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was Process Engine was not able to load class because it was not on it's class path.

Solution:

1. run `mvn clean compile`
2. copy `/target/classec/com/` to `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/com`
3. refresh project in eclipse
4. run again

It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your class `com.nuc.service.DoService` does implement either `org.activiti.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate` or `org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.delegate.ActivityBehavior`?

Comment: I modified my DoService
public class DoService implements JavaDelegate{

 public void execute(DelegateExecution arg0) throws Exception {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  System.out.println("service task");
 }
}
Even now getting the same exception

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call a java class, you can also use
 activiti: class =" com.nuc.service.DoService "